# How to merge two datasets with different information on same subjects in R?

Tags: r, merge, dataset

Suppose I have two datasets.

```
id age disease1
a1   1        1
a2   2        1
b1   3        0
b2   4        1
```

And

```
id age disease2
a1   1        1
a2   2        1
a3   5        1
b1   3        0
b2   4        1
```

I would like to combine the information in the two datasets and make a new one that looks like:

```
id age      disease1 disease2
a1   1             1        1
a2   2             1        1
a3   5          <NA>        1
b1   3             0        0
b2   4             1        1
```

The tricky part is that the two datasets have different information on the same subjects, but dataset2 has more rows. I have tried using cbind() etc, but it didn't work.

Comment: go with dplyr and join()

Comment: You tagged the question with `merge`.  Did you try that function?

Comment: @RichardScriven Yes, I have tried that. It throw away the info of a3.

Comment: I seem to be getting the right result with `merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE)`

Comment: Read the documentation at `?merge` to see the different ways it can be used. Ditto for `?cbind` or any other function.